# React native schedule a job

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, data-synchronization

I am new to react-native, i am developing an application in which i have to sync data to the server.
The idea is to sync the data after certain period of time (e.g minutes or hours) when the app is in front/background .

to achieve this, do i have use react native timers function such

> setInterval

to keep syncing data to the server while app is open and to the sync data in background do i have to use

> Headless JS
>   .

I am not sure what approach should I use. I am open to suggestions or what are the best practices to sync data to the server after certain period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a recurring background task that executes periodically even when app is closed is pretty easy to do in React Native now.

Integrate [react native background task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) to actually schedule your function with your syncing logic that gets fired in the background periodically.

Caveats of cross platform background tasks:

- Minimum interval to execute the task in background is ~15 min.
- Task execution timeout limit is 30 seconds.
- Task is not guaranteed to execute exactly at interval specified. iOS/Android uses a variety of signals to determine if task execution should be delayed (battery life/current cpu usage/etc).

If you have more advanced tasks you need to process in the background, integrate [react native queue](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue#os-background-task-full-example) into your app for job management. The queue will handle all the logic dealing with the hard 30 second timeout limit set by the OS for you (ctrl+f "queue lifespan") and it will persist your tasks across device restarts as well as handle retry-on-failure, individual task timeouts, etc, for you.

[I've written a detailed tutorial on accomplishing this here.](https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a)